# Myths about batteries

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, specific-question, reopen-request

I asked [a borderline question](https://superuser.com/q/458865/83694) on 07 August 2012.  I asked what the **pros and cons were for different rechargeable battery types**, using a context of applying those battery types.

The question was borderline because it was teetering on the edge of off topic for Super User.

Close votes for the question were scattered, but the majority called it "not a real question":

> ### closed as not a real question by [Luke](https://superuser.com/users/24010/luke), [Zoredache](https://superuser.com/users/2057/zoredache), [Gareth](https://superuser.com/users/73637/gareth), [Randolph West](https://superuser.com/users/3463/randolph-west), [Nifle](https://superuser.com/users/2013/nifle) Aug 8 at 7:45
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

To be honest, my question seems as ambiguous, vague, broad, and rhetorical as [this other question](https://superuser.com/q/318724/83694).

My hopes were to collect credible answers that debunk myths about how batteries perform.

---

I'd be happy to improve the question to make it more focused or clear, but I'm not exactly sure what is wrong with the question in its current form after seeing the [weighing of SSDs question](https://superuser.com/q/318724/83694).

If "not a real question" is not the case and the question really is off topic for Super User, I don't really know where else to ask.

- [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) seemed viable because my goal is to disprove myths about batteries with credible evidence.  I would have chosen to ask here, but Super User seemed a better fit at the time.
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is more suited to designing and theory rather than applications.
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) is about experiments and more theory.
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/) made sense because I wanted the practical aspect of computers, and as far as I know, laptop batteries count as computer hardware.

**What's the proper action to take for my question?**

This is what I can come up with:

1. Fix the question so that it's a better Q&A fit for Super User.
2. Migrate the question to Skeptics, but omit the parts about computer hardware.
3. Forget it.  It's not worth the effort to get answers on Stack Exchange.

Comment: It is not that your question is any worse than the SSD one, its just that the SSD one was older, and standards were more lax back then. (that question is woefully out of date as well)

Comment: Go with option 1 IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To be honest, my question seems as ambiguous, vague, broad, and rhetorical as this other question.

- How on-topic or unanswerable your question is and how on-topic another question is do not relate to each other in any way. Just because one question slips through the cracks doesn't entitle you to ask a similarly broad question.

> If "not a real question" is not the case and the question really is off topic for Super User, I don't really know where else to ask.

- Stack Exchange makes no guarantee that your question will have a home on one of our sites. We'll do our best to find an appropriate site for the question if we can, and can migrate to any site of your choosing *if* it's on-topic there, but it's entirely possible for any given question that there might not be an appropriate SE site for it.
- Furthermore, if your question is too broad on one site, it won't be any less broad on another site.

> 1. Fix the question so that it's a better Q&A fit for Super User.
> 2. Migrate the question to Skeptics, but omit the parts about computer hardware.
> 3. Forget it. It's not worth the effort to get answers on Stack Exchange.

- I would suggest the first option. In its present (and original) state, the question was vague at best. I'm not really sure what you're asking. To quote the FAQ, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."  Your question is *very* chatty, and it's hard to tell what you're actually asking. Cut it down to the core question: what problem do you want to solve? Right now (once you dig through the long irrelevant sections on your battery vision quest) you're asking at least 4 different questions.

Comment: Since it seems that I want multiple questions answered, is it acceptable to create a question like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/1038828)?  One answer would link to other Stack Exchange answers that clarify each question I want answered?